# extjs 4.2.1 - wrap layout container around component

Tags: javascript, html, css, user-interface, extjs

I have an outer Panel and an inner Panel.  The inner panel has a Ext.form.Label that just says "Hello World".  How would I use the framework to force the inner panel to wrap around the Label component?  I can't seem to find anything in the API that would let me do this.  In native Android code, you would simple specify "wrap_content" in the XML file, but I'm not sure how to do it here.

edit:
What i'm trying to create is a component similar to this datepicker-toolbar widget from kayak.com.  I already have all the parts I need to construct it (I think), but what I'm trying to avoid doing is hardcoding widths.  I just want the sizing to be based on the default sizes of the components.  This is a small UI piece that will be placed into a form with many other widgets:

[image]

Comment: What does the outer panel have to do with it? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: updated question.  I mentioned the outer panel because I was used to setting up UIs in Android where it was required to have an 'outer' layout container.  I wasn't sure if it was the same with ExtJS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a sample fiddle:

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/2rj

Code:

```
Ext.application({
    name : 'Fiddle',

    launch : function() {
        new Ext.container.Container({
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            layout: 'hbox',
            items: [{
                xtype: 'datefield'
            }, {
                xtype: 'component',
                html: ' - ',
                margin: '0 10'
            }, {
                xtype: 'datefield'
            }, {
                xtype: 'label',
                html: '10 Nights',
                margin: '5 0 0 100'
            }]
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Ok thx for the reply.  I was able to get this far on my own :p.  What would you suggest for the right hand side of this widget where the text and 'X' link are.  Should I just extend Ext.Component and do my own tpl?  Also, if I wanted to add some spacing between the right date field and the text on the right, is there some kind of Space widget?

Comment: In exactly the same way. Margins + a component. Updated answer.

Comment: Also, this is why you post your code. I don't know what you're up to.